# Is there a way for formatting my questions and answers?

Tags: support, formatting

Other people have such beautifully formatted questions and answers, and I have to do it basic HTML. Are there any special keys you have to use in order to have a 'touched up' post? and can someone please show me all the formats?

Answer (score 2):

When you ask a question, to the right side of the page there is a block that shows the basic markups to format a page; it contains also a link to the [formatting help](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Kiamlaluno gave you, you must know that this site uses [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).

Most tags you'll see in that page are used here. I'll give you some quick examples:

> - Use of **>** before a paragraph, to make it look like this rectangle I'm writing in.

- Or `[link name](www.example.com)` to make links in comments.
- Links in answers are different. When you are writing an answer, to make it the simple way, do the following:

  1. Click the chain button;
  2. Paste the link;
  3. Write the "link name".

You'll see its structure and so you'll be able to edit it without making it from the start.