# What's difference between oed.com and oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com

Tags: discussion, american-english

Could you help me to compare oed.com vs Oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com
Are they both from Oxford University? Where can I find a list of Oxford official website?

Comment: Hello, Nam N. Yes, you're not the only one to find the way the Oxford Languages people keep changing things confusing. I still remember 'Oxford Dictionary Online, ODO, morphing to Lexico. It's all change again since then. Perhaps most of the info [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13240/rip-oxford-living-dictionaries/13241#13241) (and in the linked threads) is still relevant. // OED and 'Oxford Languages' dictionary are published by the same company (Oxford University Press) but are totally different resources.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and the recent merge with Dictionary.com muddying things further.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com an official website from Oxford University Press?

Comment: [What's the relationship between various Oxford dictionaries? (OED vs ODO vs ODE vs NOAD)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/499693/44619)

Comment: @Mari-LouA in the link they don't mention oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com . I don't know what kind of Oxford dictionaries I am learning. Should I give up learning Oxford dictionaries and switch to other American dictionaries which are more consistent?