# Henpecked by MetaEd

Tags: discussion, content-disputes

[What is the wife of a henpecked husband called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/487141/what-is-the-wife-of-a-henpecked-husband-called/487171?noredirect=1#comment1176759_487171)

No idea why you are classifying my response as plagiarism.  Really none at all.

Comment: Not everyone can see deleted posts, so we don’t have any idea why either.

Comment: There is a slight argument for the lack of a source being attributed to a quote. But I find no reason to see why that couldn't have been addressed with a friendly comment rather than a deletion. Many people will say give opinion without backing it with a source (or attribution), and have it be considered acceptable. I don't think that anybody can reasonably say that the word *harridan* couldn't have been looked up in any dictionary and be found to be what you said it was.

Comment: Thought the link and quoted text box would have been sufficient.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 9):

The principal problem is that you did not cite your quote. I've done that for you on this occasion in order that the post can be undeleted.

**Quoting from a search engine is insufficient.** You need to cite the original source. This is explained in the [Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) to which MetaEd linked in his comment and in the [ELU Help page on referencing](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). We also have relevant questions on Meta.ELU: [What to do about missing source attributions?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/what-to-do-about-missing-source-attributions/4981?r=SearchResults&s=2|13.3313#4981) and ["New attribution rules"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/new-attribution-rules/5196?r=SearchResults&s=1|20.3402#5196)

> `— Oxford Dictionaries 
>   ([Definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harridan) 
>   and [synonyms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/harridan)) 
>   via [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=harridan&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN).`
>
> — Oxford Dictionaries ([Definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harridan) and [synonyms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/harridan)) via [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=harridan&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN).

Note also what the Meta.SE page says:

> Remember, you still have to write an actual answer, in your own words. A post that consists only of copied text, even when attributed, is not your work either.

That may mean that your post will be deleted again, even with the attribution added. In order to avert that possibility, edit it to explain **why** you like "harridan" and **why** "a strict, bossy, or belligerent old woman" is someone who henpecks.

Comment: Some take an even stricter view, for example tchrist: ["SWR responses with only copied-in text, howsoever duly attributed, are not actual answers anywhere in Stack Exchange. You haven’t written anything, so you were given notice of this in order that you might have the opportunity to do something to fix."](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11641/71848). Not sure if it's policy now given the many down votes but I remember him feeling quite strongly about it (in the comments).

Comment: It's SE policy, given the [highly upvoted] Meta.SE post; that's why I've warned that deletion is still possible. I suppose a bossy woman might be a henpecker, but it would be good to see the answer itself justify the choice.

Comment: @jjj I find this application to be inconsistent and, therefore, capricious in this particular context. (I also don't agree with this, to me, seemingly ultra-conservative approach.) A simple friendly comment would have sufficed. The deletion of this *particular* post at least *appears* to have been part of a campaign that had every single post criticized as *subjective*—and the question itself put on hold, until it was restored by community opinion. While arguably justifiable on its own, the overall moderation of this thread as a whole has the appearance of a biased ulterior motive.

Comment: @JJJ It's not just fine, because [SE policy says it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do). I'm not sure what the "leave like" question has to do with this, because I correctly cite the question and don't make any other quotations.

Comment: Will [Davo's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/487357/44619) be undeleted too?  The source is clearly attributed, the quotation is formatted correctly, it is an *answer*.

Comment: @JasonBassford I see what you [did there](https://seinfeldlaw.com/2018/06/01/the-voice-standards-of-review-capricious-and-arbitrary/). If only Stack Exchange were subject to [Administrative Procedure Act Section 706(2)(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/5/706), that'd be something, huh? ;)

Comment: Ha. I just added some original, hopefully non-opinion-based content and moved for undeletion of my answer.

Comment: @Davo MetaEd is no longer a moderator, it is therefore easier to undelete your answer. I have cast my vote for undeletion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA wow, this is a blast from the past. Thanks very much!